# Rubocop warning: Style/EndOfLine has the wrong namespace

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm working with Ruby under Windows platform. Solving "Carriage return character missing" rubocop offenses, I created file `.rubocop.yml` in the root of my project:

```
Style/EndOfLine:
  EnforcedStyle: lf
```

This solved my "Carriage return" problem. But new warning appears:

> ~/project/.rubocop.yml:Style/EndOfLine has the wrong namespace - should be Layout

What does it mean "wrong namespace - should be Layout"? At current moment I have no idea where to dig to fix it.

Comment: Need to use `Layout/EndOfLine` because "EndOfLine" rubucop works in [Layout department](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/cops.md#layout)

Thanks Andrew Marshall for answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s [`Layout/EndOfLine`](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_layout/#layoutendofline), not `Style/EndOfLine`. The part before the `/` is the namespace.

Answer (score 4):

To remove this warning need to use Layout/EndOfLine instead of Style/EndOfLine. EndOfLine is a [rubucop cop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/cops.md#cops) that responsible for detecting offense related to indentation, because it placed in Layout department.

```
  Layout/EndOfLine:
    EnforcedStyle: lf
```

It is interesting why in [this comment](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/4293#issuecomment-297719539) about fixing "Carriage return character missing" advised to use Style/EndOfLine. It's relative new article and comments. Looks like since April some changes in rubocop been added.

Comment: If you read following comments in the same issue you will find the [correct answer](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/4293#issuecomment-308653772). Looking at the [history of that cop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/commits/master/lib/rubocop/cop/layout/end_of_line.rb) you can see that the namespace changed on April 15th this year

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to indent that second line:

```
Style/EndOfLine:
  EnforcedStyle: lf
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not the cause for the message, I think.

Comment: Got it. Looks like Andrew Marshall's answer has the correct namespace.